# Display the result from a jQuery into a PHP variable

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown select list populated from a data table. The list contains the description and a value. The value is the name of a image file.

What I am trying to do is when a selection is made trigger the JQuery code and pass the result to a PHP variable.

This is the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(function() {
        $("#DepositoryImage").on("change", function() {
            $("#companyimage").text($("#DepositoryImage").val());
        });
    });
});
```

I have a PHP session varibale named $_SESSION['companyimage.], is it possible to pass "#companyimage" to $_SESSION['companyimage.] so I can pis[lay the image in a HTML form as

```
<img src="<?php print $_SESSION['companyimage.];?>" />
```

Many thanks for any time you have give.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'changeVariable.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {variable: $("#companyimage").text()},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("Succeed!"); // alerts are annoying, console is awesome
    }
});
```

Then create changeVariable.php file, and put this in it:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['companyimage']=$_POST['variable'];
?>
```

Comment: Mateusz Sowiński@ , Hi and thanks for your reply. If the dropdown list already has the result as the selected value is it nessessary to call it again or am I missing something.

Comment: you mean the "variable"? set it to whatever you want